# Find the derivative with respect to $x$ of the given combination at the given value of $x$.

Tags: calculus

Suppose that the function $f$ and $g$ and their derivatives with respect to $x$ have the following values at the given values of $x$. Find the derivative with respect to $x$ of the given combination at the given value of $x$.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 x & f(x) & g(x) & f'(x) & g'(x) \\ \hline
3 & 1 & 4 & 6 & 7 \\ \hline
4 & -3 & 3 & 5 & -4 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$$\sqrt{g(x)}, \hspace{7mm} x=3$$

I have no idea where to even start with this problem.

Thank you

Comment: What is the given combination?

Comment: @E.O. Sorry about that! Just added the combination in.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{d}{dx}g(x)^{1/2}=\frac12g(x)^{-1/2}g'(x)$$

**Added:** Let $h(x)=x^{1/2}$. Then $g(x)^{1/2}=h(g(x))$. By the chain rule
$$\frac{d}{dx}h(g(x))=h'(g(x))g'(x)=\frac12g(x)^{-1/2}g'(x)$$
We want to find the derivative at $x=3$ and so from your table we know that $g(3)=4$ and $g'(3)=7$ so
$$\frac{d}{dx}g(x)^{1/2}=\frac12g(x)^{-1/2}g'(x)=\frac12(4)^{-1/2}(7)=\frac74$$

Comment: would you be able to explain this? i know the answer is 7/4

Comment: @MadinaW Go you know the chain rule?

Comment: Do you know how i would apply the chain rule to get the answer? I am unsure what the derivative of g(x) is.

Comment: @MadinaW  You call the derivative $g'(x)$ even though you don't know its formula. Then you realise that you don't actually need to know the formula for this problem because all you need to know is the value of $g'(3)$, which you were told in the original table.

Answer (score 1):

First note that the **chain rule** is
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))= \frac{d}{dg(x)}f(g(x)) \frac{d}{dx}g(x)
$$
So now we have
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left[g(x)^{\frac12}\right]=\frac12 g(x)^{-\frac12}\frac{d}{dx}g(x)= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{g(x)}}\frac{d}{dx}g(x)$$
Therefore
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left[g(3)^{\frac12}\right] = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{g(3)}}\frac{d}{dx}g(3) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{4}}\cdot7 = \frac{7}{2\cdot 2} = \frac74$$